# asp .net 4.0 autonumeric textchnaged Autopostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback

I'm using autonumeric 1.4.5 to format a textBoxlike this

```
function pageLoad() {
  jQuery(function () {
     $('input.auto').autonumeric();
   });
}
```

I have a textBox inside a userControl with AutoPostBack="True" and a method for the event TextChanged.
It works if i enter a numeric with 3 digits or less, but not for four or above.
The autonumeric method seems to disable the autobostback.

Answer (score 0):

The version you are using is really, really old (years old!) and is not supported anymore.

You should try the [latest stable](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/releases/tag/v4.1.0) `v4.1.0` with was released today.